# Visual Studio 2019 Class Dropdown is Auto-Syncing immediately after selection

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Running Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. Recently updated to version 16.10.1

Now when I make a selection in the Class dropdown in the Navigation bar at the top of the text editor, it immediately syncs with the view and reverts the selection to the Class and Method that is under the current caret position. So essentially it ignores my selection and reverts back to what was previously selected. It has eliminated the 'Navigation' functionality of the 'Navigation bar'.

It seems to coincide with the recent update.

I've searched through options to see if this is an option that got turned on by accident, but no luck.

Is this an option that can be disabled? Or is this a new bug? Has anybody else seen this behavior?

Comment: 16.10.2 was released today. Try updating. That said, this would be better served by submitting feedback to Microsoft directly through the Send Feedback button in the top right of the main window.

Comment: Additionally, the behavior you describe is not reproducible in either 16.10.1 or 16.10.2

Comment: Thanks, @Casey, I was not aware of the Send Feedback within the app. I updated to 16.10.2 and the behavior is still occurring. Not sure what triggered it. I've submitted feedback through the Send Feedback link and will see if I hear back.

Comment: I was working on a few other projects and noticed that this same behavior is occurring on two different projects that are VB, but on a C# project the navigator is working normally.

Comment: Unfortunately, radio silence from MS after submitting feedback including a video of the behavior. The navigation bar remains broken, but seems like it's only my system. Any insight to the inner workings on the Navigation bar to dig into what could cause this? I now how to use Search to find a method, which is very tedious. I'm probably losing 30 minutes a day just trying to navigate manually.

Comment: MS will only reply if they need more information or when the issue is being worked on, or fixed and ready for an upcoming release. Do you mind posting the video to imgur (properly cropped to avoid personal information being revealed)? I might get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Here you go, @Casey. https://imgur.com/vcThR4y  When I select a Control in the middle dropdown of the navigation bar, it used to stay on that control so I could then select an item in the right dropdown to go to that code or add new code for that method. Now whenever I click on an item in the middle dropdown, it immediately reverts back to what it was on, or it's auto-syncing to where the cursor is.

Answer (score 1):

Found that this is a known issue with version 16.10.

Reverted back to 16.9.8 and is now working again.

Could not find a way to download a previous version of Community Edition so had to upgrade to Professional.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Version-16100-release-editor-problem/1432877

Comment: It's marked as "fixed, pending release", so maayybe you'll get it in 16.11.  Hopefully not having to wait until VS2022 Release.

Comment: Good news! 16.10.3 includes this fix!

Answer (score 0):

I watched the video and I think I know what's going on.

There are two types of behavior:

- Jump to class declaration (the middle drop-down); and,
- Jump to member function declaration (right drop-down).

Jump to class declaration: Only works in header files and allows you to jump to each class's declaration.

Jump to member function declaration: Only works in implementation files, but you can jump to any member function you want for any class. *However*, only selecting a class from the middle drop-down just populates the *right* drop down of the selected class' functions and types. You must then select a function you want to jump to in the right drop-down for the cursor to actually move.

Curiously, the Visual C++ workspace makes this obvious as when you change the selection in the middle drop-down the right drop-down clears itself; forcing you to pick a function to jump to in the right drop-down if you want to use the feature. The VB workspace doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: The issue is, I can't select anything in the middle drop down. As soon as I click on an item to select it, it immediately reverts back to the previous selection. When I select one of the controls in the middle drop down, it used to stick and then load the right menu with the methods for the selected control in the middle menu. Interestingly enough yesterday it worked for about 20 seconds, then stopped. It almost looks like it's attempting to load the dropdown, running into an issue ,then reverting the selection. Does VS have a log file that may log this if that is the case?

Comment: @PaulHitchcock No idea about the log file. At this point, I'd recommend trying re-initializing the VB workspace via `Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings > No, overwrite all > Visual Basic`. If that doesn't work consider re-installing VS.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Resetting the environment settings did not work. Uninstalling and reinstalling VS did not work either. I may try downloading 16.9 to see if was related to the new version or just a coincidence.

Comment: Finally put in the right search on the correct site and found a thread on VS support site tracking this issue. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Version-16100-release-editor-problem/1432877